# Java Applet strange performance behaviour on latest JRE (7.55+)

Tags: java, applet

We use some proprietary applet from our sign provider which sign some XML. When we use JRE 6u37 applet runs with no problem - runs very fast and never freezes. But when we update our JRE to 7u55 or newer it start often to hang. Only browser restart help. Is there any way to fix this problem may be by some parameters or something else?

Here is the run code:

```
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'#{request.contextPath}/distr',
                      code:'kz.softkey.iola.applet.MainApplet',
                      archive:'iolaApplet.jar',
                      type:'application/x-java-applet',
                      mayscript:'true',
                      id:'iolaApplet',
                      name:'iolaApplet',
                      width:1, height:1} ;
    var parameters = {code:'kz.softkey.iola.applet.MainApplet', 
                    codebase:'#{request.contextPath}/distr',
                    archive:'iolaApplet.jar',
                    cache_option:'Plugin',
                    cache_archive:'iolaApplet.jar',
                    mayscript:'true',
                    scriptable:'true',
                    fileExtension:'KEYSTORE',
                    cache_archive:'iolaApplet.jar',
                    java_arguments:'-Xmx300m',
                    writesoap:'false';
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between version 7 and 6 there are some minor changes in applets implementation in jre. I found that out when my team migrated some old project from 6 to 7 and in few cases applets started to hang when user tried to modify content. In my case the change was in how tables handle firePropertyChange, when user changed something in cell infinite loop occured. If you don't have access to sources I don't think you'll be able to check what causes problem in your case.

//edit

I don't see that you call any method in deployment script to laod data from site to applet so I assume that you should be able to run it from IDE like normal application. 
If you serialize some data and send it to applet, you need to find the way to load data on applet when it runs locally.
In my case we are using custom serializator for data, we created some utilites for testing, we put serialized data in txt file and run applet locally(from IDE). 
This way it is possible to debug applet like any other app.
Debugging applet when you changed jre is hard because you usually don't know when flow of app is wrong. 
In my case we ended up with guy sitting before two screens with two applets running on two versions of java and comparing flow of applets line by line. 
He sit like this some time and we discovered small change(i dont remeber exactly but I'm pretty sure that it was one 'if' that changed and it was the reason of our problem) between java versions.

Comment: Is there any way to debug applet?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/plugin004.html